# Is it possible to use a library just for design time in delphi?

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I am trying to write a component which is loading 3D objects from obj files.
I am using **ToolsAPI** library for `GetActiveProject.FileName`. I added *designide.dcp* to Requiers part in the bpl. I registered my object and in design when I put an instance of this object on a TViewPort3D which I put before everything is OK and I can see the object from the obj file is loaded in the scene, but when I try to compile the project I get an error that says ToolsAPI.dcu not found.

The procedure that I use for loading the obj file is (Type of Model variable is TModel3D) :

```
procedure TMyObject.LoadModel(fileName: string);
begin
  if(csDesigning in ComponentState)then
    Model.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(GetActiveProject.FileName))+'Obj\'+filename)
  else
    Model.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+'Obj\'+filename);
end;
```

This procedure is used in constructor as follow (TMyObject inherited from TDummy):

```
constructor TMyObject.Create(AOwner:TComponent)
begin
  inherited;
  Model:=TModel3D.Create(Self);
  Model.Parent:=Self;
  LoadModel('Object1.obj');
end;
```

Is there anyway to prevent using the ToolsAPI library when the host project for the component is about to compile?

I just thinking about something like directives as follow.

```
{$IFDEF DESIGNTIME}    
uses ToolsAPI;    
{$ENDIF}
```

But is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you are trying to compile the design time code into a run time project. Either a run time package, or an executable. That's not allowed. You simply cannot compile any of the ToolsAPI units into a project that is not a design time package.

You can certainly use conditional compilation to exclude the ToolsAPI units, but you will have to define your own conditional define. There is no built-in conditional that will serve your needs.

But using conditional compilation is probably not the best solution. Typically you would separate the code that used Tools API into distinct units, and only include those units in the design time projects.

So the code for your component would be split into, say, two units. The first unit, `uMyComp.pas`, say, contains the bulk of the code. This unit declares the component and provides its implementation.  Nothing in `uMyComp.pas` makes any reference to ToolsAPI. The second unit, `uMyCompReg.pas` say, performs the component registration and any other tasks that require the ToolsAPI. There is a dependency between these units in that `uMyCompReg.pas` uses `uMyComp.pas`. Then your design time package will include both units, and any other projects that are not design time will include only `uMyComp.pas`.

---

You could achieve the same effect using conditionals. The design time project would define a conditional to indicate that this was design time. So the project settings might include a definition of a conditional named `DESIGNTIME`. Then all the code for your component would reside in a unit named `uMyComp.pas`, say. Any code related to design time would be conditional on `DESIGNTIME`. And any other projects that included `uMyComp.pas` would not have `DESIGNTIME` defined and so would omit the design time only code.

Whilst this is possible it is not, in my view, the best way to solve the problem. Indeed if you look around the wealth of open source examples of component development I'd be surprised if you found any that handled the separation of design time code from run time code using conditionals.

---

How would you separate the ToolsAPI code into a design time unit? Here's the problem method:

```
procedure TMyObject.LoadModel(fileName: string);
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    Model.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(
      ExtractFilePath(GetActiveProject.FileName))+'Obj\'+filename)
  else
    Model.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(
      ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+'Obj\'+filename);
end;
```

First of all, let's look at the commonality of this code. The first think to observe is that the outsides of the call to `LoadFromFile` are the same. Only in the middle, the choice of directory, is there variation. So let's write it like this:

```
procedure TMyObject.LoadModel(fileName: string);
var
  ModelDir: string;
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    ModelDir := ExtractFilePath(GetActiveProject.FileName)
  else
    ModelDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  Model.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ModelDir)+'Obj\'+filename);
end;
```

The problem for you is how to move `GetActiveProject.FileName` into the design time code. You need to use dependency injection (DI) to do this. Allow some other party to supply the logic. You need to make `TMyObject` ignorant of this particular detail. You could use a DI framework for this, but that's perhaps a little heavyweight just for this one task. So instead let's declare a class variable that holds a function pointer:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(...)
  ...
  public
    class var GetModelDir: TFunc<string>;
  end;
```

This function point allows other parties, external to the class, to specify how the model directory is located. Now `LoadModel` becomes:

```
procedure TMyObject.LoadModel(fileName: string);
var
  ModelDir: string;
begin
  if Assigned(GetModelDir) then
    ModelDir := GetModelDir()
  else
    ModelDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  Model.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ModelDir)+'Obj\'+filename);
end;
```

At this point, your code can now be used outside of a design time package. The next step is to add code to specify `GetModelDir` at design time. This code goes in the design time only unit that also registers the component. The obvious place for the code is in the initialization section of that unit. It looks like this:

```
initialization
  TMyObject.GetModelDir := 
    function: string
    begin
      Result := GetActiveProject.FileName;
    end;
```

I've used anonymous methods here, but you could equally use method of object, or plain old functional types, depending on your Delphi version.

Comment: How about I add code to my answer to show how to write LoadModel?

Comment: @ David The idea of declaring the global function variable just worked and I accept your answer as the true one. :D but I still think that I didn't get the thing which you and Craig mentioned. If you put a small code about the things that you said it would be great and I may get more knowledge from this. and maybe helpful for the others who want take a different solution. you said that by directives it can be done. so I really curious how could it be done. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Do you have separate design time and runtime projects. Are you using runtime projects?

Comment: No. I don't! But It would be nice to learn the thing that you said. as you mentioned there is 2 way for solving this matter.

Comment: There's nothing more to say that I did already. Define the conditional in the project options of your design time package. Then use it in IFDEFs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but preferably not with conditional defines as this would create far more complications and restrictions than it's worth.

- You need to separate your code into different units according to whether it's design-time code or run-time code.

  - E.g. For a single component, the bulk of the (with no ToolsAPI dependency) goes into one unit.
  - A second unit performs component registration and perhaps provides custom design-time editors for the component.
  - The second unit uses the first and you have a clean separation without conditional defines.
- You then create 2 separate packages: design-time and run-time.
- The design time package will have a dependency on the ToolsAPI.
- Make sure that none of the run-time units use any of the design-time units.
- If any design-time units use run-time units (very likely) then the design-time package will *require* the run-time package.

With the above package structure, your application that uses your new components should only have dependencies on the run-time units.

Comment: I think it could be done with compiler directives. I don't think that's a good idea, but I see no reason why you could not use directives to exclude the code that uses tools api.

Comment: @David perhaps but not without creating serious headaches with other package functionality. The conditional define would effectively mean two different units with the same name. So splitting design-time & run-time packages becomes a problem: A cannot _require_ B because they need different functionality in the same unit. But iirc you cannot simultaneously load packages with duplicate unit names.

Comment: That's a good point. It would work fine if you did not use runtime packages. And for run time packages you'd need two distinct packages. One for design time and one for run time. But then it is normal to have a design time package and a run time package anyway. I'm not saying it is a good idea, I just think that your first paragraph is a little strong. And it's worth considering how it would work with conditionals to see all the flaws and then decide to do it the standard way!

Comment: @David & @ Craig Thanks for your answers. I don't understand how can I split my class code in 2 units? I have just one class that has a LoadModel procedure in its private section. This procedure depend on `(csDesigning in ComponentState)` statement decides to use which path for loading the obj file. I got the idea to put the register procedure in the other unit. but can I say to my class that implementation of one procedure will be done in the other unit?

Comment: Declare a variable that holds a function. Either a public class var in your component, or a global variable. The component calls this function, if it is assigned, to get the model directory. If not assigned it uses ParamStr(0). The design time code assigns to the function variable a function that uses tools api to get model directory.